# SQL select query order by on where in

Tags: sql, sql-server

How Can I make the order by based on what I input on where?

**example query**

```
select * from student where stud_id in (
'5',
'3',
'4'
)
```

**the result would be**

```
id|   name  |
5 |  John   |
3 |  Erik   |
4 | Michael |
```

Kindly help me thanks.

Comment: Order only ensured by ORDER BY clause.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think you need another hidden input column so that you can `order by` that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is with a derived table:

```
select s.*
from student s cross join
     (values (5, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)
     ) v(stud_id, ord)
     on v.stud_id = s.stud_in
order by v.ord;
```

`stud_id` looks like a number so I dropped the single quotes.  Numbers should be compared to numbers.  If it is really a string, then use the single quotes.

Comment: That would be hassle if I gonna query a hundred +

Comment: If you don't have the list in a table in the database, then you need to list them somehow.

Comment: I think I'll accept this for now because this is a right answer but too much work. If this is the only possible then its fine. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon mentioned, you need something to provide order. An IN clause doesn't have a pre-defined order, just like a table doesn't. Rather than numbering the row order yourself, you could have a table variable do it like this:

```
DECLARE TABLE @StudentIDs
(
    StudentIDKey int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentID int
);

INSERT @StudentIDs (StudentID)
VALUES 
(5),
(3),
(4);

SELECT *
FROM Student AS s
INNER JOIN @StudentIDs AS id
ON s.StudentID = id.StudentID
ORDER BY id.StudentIDKey;
```

That should be far easier if you have a lot of values to work with.

Hope that helps.